# AngularJS bind function to ajax ($http) start/end/error

Tags: angularjs

I would like to attach a function that gets executed whenever Angular is making an $http request.  What I'm trying to do is essentially show a loading spinner whenever any Ajax Requests are being made by any App.  In jQuery I have done this in the past by:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
        $(this).show();
    }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
 });
```

Any insight into how I can attach a function that shows and hides a loading div whenever any controller throughout the application performs an Ajax Request?

Maybe there is a better way (directives?)

Thanks!

Alessandro Ferrucci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing that monitors all traffic in the app are the httpInterceptors youll have to write an inteceptor as a service that shows your div, when a request is detected and hides it when a response is detected. 
interceptor are creaeted as services and passed to the $HttpProvider at config time.
you can read about it  here
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks!  This sounds exactly like what I'm looking for, will give it a shot later.